# Java - Brute Forcing Algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion, generator

I've been trying to make a brute forcing algorithm, but it doesn't seem to work. It stops after three Strings generated and freezes.

Here's my code:

```
public static final char[] CHARSET_1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890./,[]\;\'\"".toCharArray();
public final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);

protected void recur(final String base, final int times) {
    if (base.length() < times) {
        for (final char c : CHARSET_1) {
            final String b = base + c;
            System.out.println("Current: " + b);
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    recur(b, times);
                } // I also tried it without the executor, same results.
            });
        }
    }
}

public void bruteforce() {
    final Thread generator = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            recur("", 5);
        }
    });
    generator.start();
}
```

In the function
`recur("", 5);`, 5 means the generate strings up to the length of 5 + 1.

Here's the output I get:

```
a
aa
aaa
```

Then it freezes. I cannot figure out why. I think it might be a memory leak issue, but I don't know. I also tried it without ThreadPools, but I seem to get the same issue...

Any help is appreciated, thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Are you sure it freezes in recur and not in whatever it does when recur exits?  What is the code that calls recur?

Comment: @MattJordan Edited the question!

Comment: Does it work without any of the thread-related code? Here is a standalone test: https://codeshare.io/14l0V Does this run correctly?

Comment: If you remove thread generator and remove the executor service, let all in the main thread, this still occurs? because here work with no problem at all